# Can calling an asynchronous method using .GetResult() cause a deadlock?

Tags: c#, async-await, locking

Can I use this approach safely (without risk of deadlock):

```cs
public class Foo
{
  private readonly object locker = new();

  public void Test() 
  {
     lock(locker) 
     {
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     }
  }
}
```

Or should we use something like [Nito.AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx):

```cs
public class Bar
{
  private readonly AsyncLock mutex = new();

  public async Task Test() 
  {
     using (await mutex.LockAsync())
     {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: TLDR no it isn't safe in ASP.NET Classic, WinForms and WPF applications, among others. Console apps are OK, but would still avoid if you can. You can use a `SemaphoreSlim` for an async lock if you want to avoid a dependency